# When developing enterprise web applications, what is the best way to include an element or set of elements that appears in a number of pages?

Tags: web-applications, repeat, jspinclude, code-maintainability

For eg: If I have a navigation section with a number of links/buttons in it and this needs to be included in several pages (jsps), what is the best way to do this in a maintainable fashion? Would I do this by a jsp include?

Answer (score 0):

yes doing `<jsp:include>` would be a good option .. including same section in several pages would result in reusability of ur section..and moreover its an easy task to do that ..